# Test cases of beforeInterceptor

Tags: unit-testing, grails, testing, integration-testing, spock

Following is my `beforeInterceptor`

```
def beforeInterceptor = {
    log.debug "============${actionName}=========="       
    if (!(actionName in ['search'])) {
        redirect controller: 'error', action: 'denied'
        return false
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to write test of `beforeInterceptor`. I have googled for it but no luck. I have `tried` to write its test cases on my own but not able to get `actionName` in the beforeInterceptor.

```
when:
    controller.beforeInterceptor()
```

or

```
when:
    controller.beforeInterceptor.call()
    controller.history(ticket)
```

Each time I got null in `actionName`.

Someone any idea: **how to write test cases of beforeInterceptor** (`integration` or `unit`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created unit test for this, we can set action name in request there. And I called beforeInterceptor directly like:

```
@TestFor(PersonController)
@Mock([Person])
class PersonControllerSpec extends Specification {

  def setup() {
  }

  def cleanup() {
  }

  void "test beforeInterceptor"() {
    when:
    webRequest.actionName = "index"
    controller.beforeInterceptor()

    then:
    controller.response.redirectedUrl == '/error/denied'

    when:
    controller.response.reset()
    webRequest.actionName = "search"
    controller.beforeInterceptor()

    then:
    controller.response.redirectedUrl != '/error/denied'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Grails does not invoke interceptors or servlet filters when calling
>   actions during integration testing. You should test interceptors and
>   filters in isolation, using functional testing if necessary.

It will be easier to [use and test with a **filter**](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/guide/testing.html#unitTestingFilters) instead.